# YouTube LiveStream API accessNotConfigured error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm building a Swift app for streaming video to YouTube, but I can't get past the `liveBroadcast`-insertion step. The app prints out a cURL representation of each request it makes; this is the insertion one:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%252CcontentDetails%252Csnippet%252Cstatus&key=<app-key>" \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'\
    --data '{"kind":"youtube#liveBroadcast","snippet":{"title":"Simulator","scheduledStartTime":"2019-09-04T18:18:50Z"},"status":{"privacyStatus":"public"}}'
```

This gives me the following error response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Project <redacted> is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable YouTube Data API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=40586258927 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=<redacted>"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Project <redacted> is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable YouTube Data API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=<Foo> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

I'm not sure where it's getting the name `Project <redacted>`, as that doesn't match the project that I logged into.

I've checked the following SO questions, to no avail:

- [youtube analytics api error 403, accessNotConfigured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202461/youtube-analytics-api-error-403-accessnotconfigured)
   This one is 6 years old, and there's no longer a YouTube Analytics API. My project *does* have the YouTube Data API enabled.
- [Youtube API key - accessNotConfigured error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409502/youtube-api-key-accessnotconfigured-error) I also tried creating a whole new YouTube project, but that didn't work.
- and others.

Answer (score 0):

I also started getting this same error, same problem, no explanation, around the same time as you.

Comment: But it worked for you before? I've never gotten it to work.

Comment: Just got it to work yesterday. Our problem was, the GSuite user account that created the corresponding Developers Console Project no longer had permission to use the Google Cloud Console. After we re-enabled that user's ability to use the Cloud Console in the GSuite Admin Console for our domain, it started working again. Hope that helps!